# Google Drive api client scope giving prob

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api, android-googleapiclient

I want to list the files and folders in google drive of any user with my app. I am using the following code:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .addApi(Drive.API)
                        .addScope(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"))
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(connectionCallbacks)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(connectionFailedListener)
                        .build();

mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

It is resulting ConnectionFailed and showing a dialog  is having trouble with Google Play services. But if I replace the GoogleApiClient's scope to `.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)` connection is working fine, but resulting no file listing from the google drive. What is problem in my code? **Is there any restriction of normal Google API credential regarding scope?**

Comment: I think you did well by using .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE). Did you implement your onConnectionFailedListener and ConnectionCallbacks as stated in this [Android guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client) ?

Comment: The Google Drive Android API only supports file and appfolder scopes.
See here: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_the_google_drive_android_api